# React Testing Library: testing props sent to mocked child component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

using jest and react testing library.

this seems so fundamental, yet i am missing it.  how do you mock out a child component, but test that parent is calling it with the correct props?  in this case i want to test parent.js and mock out the child component.

parent.js

```
import Child from './child'
const Parent = (props) => {
  const {firstname} = props;

  <Child name={firstname} />
}
```

test.js

```
import Parent from '../parent'
jest.mock('./child');

it('should render properly'), () => {
   render(<Parent firstname='bob'/>);
   expect('child').toBeCalledWith({ name: 'bob' });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should mock the Child module using `jest.fn()` and test for the props it's called with.

This might help:
https://dev.to/d_ir/verifying-children-passed-to-react-mock-components-2mf9